# Simple webpage coming up White in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have this simple web page, that I thought I had tested in every browser.  Then I tried it in Internet Explorer, and it just showed a blank white page.  I went through my CSS, looking for lines that IE didn't support, and found background = rgba(some stuff), but this is in a div not shown by IE.  Does anybody have any ideas on what might be causing this?  The webpage is at http://heather.sh/qr
Below is my HTML.

```
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<script>
function ifUIWebView() {
    var is_uiwebview = /(iPhone|iPod|iPad).*AppleWebKit(?!.*Safari)/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
    var isChrome = navigator.userAgent.match('CriOS');
    if (isChrome) {
        var mobile_safari_div = document.getElementById('mobile_safari_div');
        mobile_safari_div.innerHTML = mobile_safari_div.innerHTML + '<font size="3" color="black"><b>Chrome does not support contact card download.  Please open this page (<a href="http://heather.sh/qr">http://heather.sh/qr</a>) in Mobile Safari.</b></font>';
    }
    else if (is_uiwebview) {
        var mobile_safari_div = document.getElementById('mobile_safari_div');
        mobile_safari_div.innerHTML = mobile_safari_div.innerHTML + '<font size="3" color="black"><b>This browser may not support contact card download.  If it doesn\'t work, open this page (<a href="http://heather.sh/qr">http://heather.sh/qr</a>) in Mobile Safari.</b></font>';
    }
}
</script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<div id='topContainer'><img src="photo.jpg" style="visibility:hidden" width="100%"/>

<div id='container'>

<div id='download_button_div'>
<a href="/qr/download-contact/download.php"><img src="Download Contact.png" id='download_button'></img></a>
<div id='mobile_safari_div'></div>
</div>

<script>
ifUIWebView()
</script>

</div>
</div>

</body>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#topContainer{
    position: relative;
    max-width:400px;
    margin: auto;
}
#container{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("photo.jpg");
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
}
#download_button {
    width: 100%;
}
#download_button_div {
    width: 100%;
}
#mobile_safari_div {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    font-family: 'helvetica';
    text-align: center;
}
```

Any ideas on what part is incompatible with IE?  As I say, I have tried going through and could only find the rgba thing, so any help appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Any console errors?  What do you see if you view source?

Comment: @BjoernRennhak I was trying with IE9

Comment: @eidsonator If I view source, it shows the exact same source.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use

style = "display: block " instead of  style="visibility:hidden"

I am not sure this will help or not.

But try it

Comment: This means that the img is no longer there though.  With visibility:hidden, the image goes invisible, but is still there, wheras block will change the layout of the page because the image disappears.

Comment: Oh, ok - I have done this, and now in internet explorer the layout has just gone super weird.  The image is full screen.  At least it's showing something I guess.

Comment: I can't.  Look at the code - it is variable width.  The idea is that when you look on a screen of width less than 400, it scales to be the width of the screen, and when you look on a computer, it shows in a rectangle as 400px across.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem was - I had forgotten to put `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of the html.  Not sure what it does, but it fixed everything.
Thanks!
Sam